# Stroking Text on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I came across an interesting effect mixing `setLineDash` and `strokeText` in a canvas

```js
ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d")
ctx.font = "110px Arial";
i = speed = 3

function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 160)
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.setLineDash([i, 600]);
  ctx.strokeText("WORLD ふ", 10, 100);
  i += speed
  if (i > 600 || i < 2)
    speed *= -1
}

setInterval(loop, 50)
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width=600 height=160></canvas>
```

As you can see the `W` takes longer to draw than the `O` in this snippet.
Is there any property to retrieve the number of pixels (length) of the longest line of a letter?

Comment: Can it be assumed, that there is a solid color for the border (no gradient)?

Comment: @Jankapunkt not exactly sure what you mean... but surely we can make some assumptions

Comment: The best solution would probably be to force the use of a web font so all your clients get the same, and make the measurements once in a dedicated software.

Comment: @Kaiido yes makes sense, **IF** this is something that can not be retrieved and must be calculated offloading the computations to dedicated software would reduce browser load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the characters each offscreen and "count" the occurrences of the pixels (non-zero values):

```js
function getAmount (char, { width, height, font, color }) {
  // create temporary offscreen canvas
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = width
  canvas.height = height

  // draw the character
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  ctx.font = font
  ctx.strokeText(char, 0, 90)

  // get the pixels data
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height)
  let sum = 0
  imageData.data.forEach(point => {
    if (point > 0) sum++
  })
  return sum
}

const width = 90
const height = 90
const font = "90px Arial"

getAmount('W', { font, width, height }) // 940
getAmount('O', { font, width, height }) // 660
getAmount('R', { font, width, height }) // 673
getAmount('L', { font, width, height }) // 296
getAmount('D', { font, width, height }) // 613
```

You can use these values roughly as weightening the speed and draw each character indivually but keep in mind that you will have to manage placement etc. additionally. Also this only detects any non-zero value. Of you use gradients for your stroke you will have to detect the image data within the range of the gradient.

## Edit:

Since there is no source of truth to be found, we can use another trick:

Find the number of `i` that creates an offscreen image with the same amount of pixels as the full dashed character.

```js
/**
 * draws a stroked text by given params to a context
 **/

function draw (char, ctx, minValue, maxValue) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 160)
  ctx.beginPath()
  if (minValue && maxValue) {
    ctx.setLineDash([minValue, maxValue])
  }
  ctx.strokeText(char, 10, 100);
}

/**
 * Returns the amount of pixels for a given character
 */
const offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
function getAmount (char, { value, max,  width, height, font }) {
  // draw offscreen, then detect border pixels
  offscreenCanvas.width = width
  offscreenCanvas.height = height

  // draw the character
  const ctx = offscreenCanvas.getContext("2d")
  ctx.font = font
  draw(char, ctx, value, max)

  // get the pixels data
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height)
  let sum = 0
  imageData.data.forEach(point => {
    if (point > 0) sum++
  })

  return sum
}

/**
 * Returns the number of iterations required to complete a character
 **/

function getIterations (char, { font, width, height }) {
  // get amount when word is fully drawn
  const fullAmount = getAmount(char, { value: undefined, max: undefined, width, height, font })

  let iterations = 1
  let amount = 0
  do {
    amount = getAmount(char, { value: iterations, max: 1000, width, height, font })
    iterations++
  } while ((amount - fullAmount < -3) && iterations < 2000);

  return iterations
}
```

From here we can determine the `i` value for the `setLineDash` parameter:

```js
const font = "110px Arial";
const width = 110
const height = 110

const check = char => {
  const amount = getIterations(char, { font, width, height })
  console.log(char, amount)
}


check('W')  // 620
check('O')  // 243
check('R')  // 331
check('L')  // 248
check('D')  // 248
check('ふ') // 185
```

Using these values you can create a relative `speed` parameter, that allows you to complete the strokes at the same time.

Note, that this approach is super greedy and not really performance optimized, rather a proof of concept.

Comment: It counts not lines but any pixel that is drawn on the offscreen canvas. Edit: so the O may have to be divided by two when both lines are drawn simultaneously

Comment: If just the outer line is of interest what about [edge detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator)?

Comment: I managed to achieve the objective with your trick ... will post an optimized version shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimized version of [@Jankapunkt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3098783/jankapunkt) proof of concept:

```js
function letterLen(text, font) {
  const oc = document.createElement('canvas');
  oc.width = oc.height = 200;
  const octx = oc.getContext("2d");
  octx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  octx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  octx.font = font;

  function pixels(char) {
    octx.strokeText(char, 20, oc.height - 20);
    const id = octx.getImageData(0, 0, oc.width, oc.height)
    return id.data.reduce((a, c) => c ? a + 1 : a, 0)
  }

  function length(char) {
    octx.setLineDash([]);
    const full = pixels(char)
    if (full == 0) return 0
    let max = full
    let min = 0
    do {
      let iter = Math.round((min + max) / 2)
      octx.setLineDash([iter, 800]);
      if (pixels(char) > full - 10)
        max = iter
      else
        min = iter
    } while (min + 1 < max)
    return max
  }

  const strArray = text.split('');
  return strArray.map(s => length(s));
}

ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d")
ctx.font = "110px Arial";
i = delta = 3
const world = "WORLDふ"
const wlen = letterLen(world, ctx.font)
const minlen = Math.min(...wlen)

function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 900, 600)
  const letters = world.split('');
  let ix = 10
  for (j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.setLineDash([i * wlen[j] / minlen, 800]);
    ctx.strokeText(letters[j], ix, 120);
    ix += ctx.measureText(letters[j]).width
  }
  i += delta
  if (i > minlen + 10 || i < 2)
    delta *= -1
}

setInterval(loop, 50)
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width=600 height=160></canvas>
```

As we can see now all letters finish drawing at the same time